Android Native library file not found at runtim
I'm building a VPN app (using v2ray protocol) for school project and I am trying to use this (https://github.com/dev7dev/V2ray-Android) library and everything works fine if I just build the provided project files, however when I make my own project and import the module while following the instructions, I get a runtime error saying that the jnilib "libtun2socks.so" file does not exist (Cannot run program "/data/app/com.example.bobvpn5-JTEQwsRle2opKu7bKLubFg==/lib/arm64/libtun2socks.so" (in directory "/data/user/0/com.example.bobvpn5/files"): error=2, No such file or directory).
I analyzed my apk file and the file is actually in the apk but just not loaded properly. I used this piece debug code to verify:
File file = new File(getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir, "libtun2socks.so");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.d("!!!MainActivity", "libtun2socks.so exists at " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            Log.e("!!!MainActivity", "libtun2socks.so does NOT exist");
        }

and tested on both the provided project and my own. Provided project shows that it exists (as expected) and my project's debug shows that it does not exist. I also noticed this linker error for my project , that does not come up when running the provided project.
For the past 2 days I was suspicious it had to do with my gradle configs (bc my gradle + AGP version is higher than the provided project's) but now I dont know if gradle is the issue bc I've checked my configs 6 billion times, made sure correct jniSrcDirs , app-level, project-level, v2ray-level gradle configs settings etc..
I can provide anyone down to help with my project file.
THANK YOU soso much in advance, im pulling my hair out rn bc pretty much everything is same between my project and his project. PS my project is just a barebone project with no additional code that could be interfering. And theres no way its a problem with the .so native libraries because it's the same files. And also ran on the same devices with same architecture.

Recent versions of Android do not extract libraries to /data/app anymore but run them directly from the APK. Likewise, that DT_PREINIT_ARRAY thing is not relevant for shared libraries. Have you checked the unfiltered logcat output? It may contain clues.

I had the same problem. While analyzing of V2RayNG, I found this code in build.gradle (module level):
sourceSets {
    getByName("main") {
        jniLibs.srcDirs("libs")
    }
}

packaging {
    jniLibs {
        useLegacyPackaging = true
    }
}

and also make sure, that this native files are in app/libs folder

last release of libv2ray library you can find here: https://github.com/2dust/AndroidLibXrayLite/releases
